# OptionError while trying to set chained_assigment to None in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling

I want to suppress warnings from pandas just after import this way:

1) `pd.set_option('chained_assignment',None)` -- returns option error: no such keys(s): 'chained_assigment'

2) `pandas.options.mode.chained_assignment = None` -- return you can only set the value of existing options

How to set this param?

Comment: `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None` works for me. Try reloading pandas.

Comment: Which is your pandas version? Could be relevant to know